# "diff.exe" missing from Portable Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, diff, portability

Due to lack of privileges/permissions/influence/power/charm/money, I am unable to install the full Cygwin at my works computer. So instead I make do with 
[**portable Cygwin**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cygwinportable).

I was horrified to discover that good old `diff.exe` is missing from portable Cygwin.

Why is it missing?

Where can I get it from?

What else is missing?

Comment: Cygwin can actually be installed without administrator rights, using the 'Install For Just Me' option on the installer's page for choosing the installation directory. Trouble is though that the name `setup.exe` triggers Windows magic that automatically asks for administrator privileges when invoking something that looks like an installer. An easy way around that is to rename it, e.g. to `cygwin.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

The Baby Cygwin suggestion didn't work - kept getting core dumps.

My solution was to write a wrapper "diff" script in /usr/local/bin, which had something like:

```
F1=$( cygpath -w $1 )
F1=$( cygpath -w $2 )

/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/fc.exe ${F1} ${F2}
```

The output is similar to "diff -c ".

Not ideal. Still no one can tell me why Portable Cygwin is missing this command.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can try my
[**Baby Cygwin**](http://code.google.com/p/strm/downloads)

It has `diff.exe`